# Grouping pandas series into bins

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, bin

I have the following **Pandas series:**

```
Asia           China                 19.7549
               Japan                 10.2328
               India                 14.9691
               South Korea           2.27935
               Iran                  5.70772
North America  United States          11.571
               Canada                61.9454
Europe         United Kingdom        10.6005
               Russian Federation    17.2887
               Germany               17.9015
               France                17.0203
               Italy                 33.6672
               Spain                 37.9686
Australia      Australia             11.8108
South America  Brazil                 69.648
Name: % Renewable, dtype: object
```

I have **binned** this data into 5 bins:

```
binning = pd.cut(Reducedset['% Renewable'],5)
```

I want to then calculate the **number of countries** in **each** of these **bins:**

```
df.groupby(binning)['% Renewable'].agg(['count'])
```

Therefore, the final dataframe should only have the **'continents'** as the index and **not countries.**

However, this formula **does not work.**

My current output is this:

```
                     count
binning                
(2.212, 15.753]       7
(15.753, 29.227]      4
(29.227, 42.701]      2
(56.174, 69.648]      2
```

I want to display the index here for 'Continent'...

Would anybody be able to give me a helping hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you have:

- a **DataFrame** (not a *Series*) named *Reducedset*,
- with a single column named *% Renewable*,
- with a 2-level MultiIndex (*continents* and *countries*).

As binning of individual rows will be needed later, even after some
changes in the index, it is better to save *binning* as another column:

```
Reducedset['binning'] = pd.cut(Reducedset['% Renewable'], 5)
```

The result is:

```
                                  % Renewable           binning
continents    countries                                        
Asia          China                  19.75490  (15.753, 29.227]
              Japan                  10.23280   (2.212, 15.753]
              India                  14.96910   (2.212, 15.753]
              South Korea             2.27935   (2.212, 15.753]
              Iran                    5.70772   (2.212, 15.753]
North America United States          11.57100   (2.212, 15.753]
              Canada                 61.94540  (56.174, 69.648]
Europe        United Kingdom         10.60050   (2.212, 15.753]
              Russian Federation     17.28870  (15.753, 29.227]
              Germany                17.90150  (15.753, 29.227]
              France                 17.02030  (15.753, 29.227]
              Italy                  33.66720  (29.227, 42.701]
              Spain                  37.96860  (29.227, 42.701]
Australia     Australia              11.81080   (2.212, 15.753]
South America Brazil                 69.64800  (56.174, 69.648]
```

If you want to have only *continents* in the index, you can run:

```
Reducedset.reset_index('countries', inplace=True)
```

You can print it, sorted by *binning*, the result is:

```
                        countries  % Renewable           binning
continents                                                      
Asia                        Japan     10.23280   (2.212, 15.753]
Asia                        India     14.96910   (2.212, 15.753]
Asia                  South Korea      2.27935   (2.212, 15.753]
Asia                         Iran      5.70772   (2.212, 15.753]
North America       United States     11.57100   (2.212, 15.753]
Europe             United Kingdom     10.60050   (2.212, 15.753]
Australia               Australia     11.81080   (2.212, 15.753]
Asia                        China     19.75490  (15.753, 29.227]
Europe         Russian Federation     17.28870  (15.753, 29.227]
Europe                    Germany     17.90150  (15.753, 29.227]
Europe                     France     17.02030  (15.753, 29.227]
Europe                      Italy     33.66720  (29.227, 42.701]
Europe                      Spain     37.96860  (29.227, 42.701]
North America              Canada     61.94540  (56.174, 69.648]
South America              Brazil     69.64800  (56.174, 69.648]
```

So as you can see, in *(2.212, 15.753]* bin you have countries from
**4** continents, so the information about countries is still needed
(although you can have it as a "regular" column).

Now you can also perform your aggregation, but slightly changed:

```
Reducedset.groupby('binning')['% Renewable'].agg(['count'])
```

(note *Reducedset* instead of *df* and apostrophes surrounding *binning*,
as it is now a **column** in your DataFrame).

Comment: how can I include the index for 'Continent' in the final output?

Comment: Continent still is in the DataFrame, but as the **index** column. If you want it as a "regular" column run *reset_index()*.

Comment: all ok now! Figured it out. I used this formula:              

Here = Reducedset['% Renewable'].groupby([Reducedset['% Renewable'].index.get_level_values(0),pd.cut(Reducedset['% Renewable'],5)]).count()

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you don't make **silly mistakes** such as using the incorrect name for the data frame:

```
Reducedset.groupby(binning)['% Renewable'].agg(['count'])
```